# CVE-2021-38628 in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, nuxt.js, pci-compliance

Description:
Disable the use of TLSv1.0 protocol in favor of a cryptographically stronger protocol such as TLSv1.2.

> The following openssl commands can be used to do a manual test: openssl s_client -connect ip:port -tls1 If the test is successful, then the target support TLSv1

Env:
Nuxt application in dockerfile (same as any other nodejs web application)

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue either you'll need to add in your nginx conf file:

`ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;`

don't forget to replace the default configuration in nginx using docker file:

`COPY ./nginx/conf.d /etc/nginx/conf.d`

this may not solve the issue, if it's the case upgrade your node version (in my case i'm using `16.17.0-alphine`)

you can test it locally before deploying running this cmd:

`openssl s_client -connect ip:port -tls1 (and  openssl s_client -connect ip:port -tls1_1)`

should not show your certificate, then run: `openssl s_client -connect ip:port -tls1_2`

if now you're able to see your certificate only in the second command then you have successfully fixed the issue.